# JSP - Need to check for the value in the database with user given value before updating database

Tags: java, javascript, database, jsp

I have a requirement where I need to enter 3 values in a jsp form.
Production Order number , Operation  and  Quantity.

When I enter these values and click on submit , the background logic is that , 
For a given  "prod order number" and "Operation" , it should update the "Quantity" value into the database. The "Quantity" value can only be either 0 or 1 in the database.

Now my requirement is as follows :

For example , first time the user enters 
prod number=20000 , Operation=25, Quantity = 1 .

Now again , when user enters the same values for second time , 
ie., prod number=20000 , Operation = 25 , Quantity = 1

It should not again go to the database and update the the table
( overwriting the existing value which is one ).

Instead it should give an alert message like "Operation already completed".

Comment: I am going to assume the primary key is the product order number. All you would need to do is query the database with that primary key, get back the existing values and then do your comparison against the new ones coming in

Comment: Prod order number is not the primary key . They can be more than one prod order number. But,  Prod order number  and "Operation" combined together can be unique.

Comment: Primary key can consist of your all columns.

Comment: @user3254725 - Then I would use those. Since that is 2/3 of the values, your logic would be (1) If nothing came back, we're good to go (2) if something came back, check to see if the value for quantity matches what the user entered. If not, we're good. If they do, then don't save

Comment: @Everv0id - That is very true, but not relevant in regards to the comments.

Comment: My Query is '  Update table-name set quantity="xxxx" where  prod-order-number="xxxx" and operation="xxxx"  '                                                                 I need some help in how to get back the existing value and compare it with the the coming values ?  I am not able to figure out the logic to do this.  I would appreciate if you could provide me a sample code  ??

Comment: Check out `PreparedStatement`. There are plenty of examples out there to get you going :-)

Comment: I tried to Google . All I can get is Ajax examples . But i dont know it.                Can you tell me if we could do this using plain Jsp ?  Like connecting to the database , getting the value and comparing ?  in the jsp code itself without touching other things .. ?

Comment: In JSP, no. You would need to use a Java class to connect and pull the values. As for the tutorial, if you do an easy Google search of "Java PreparedStatement example" there are a LOT of examples. Here is one: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: I would NOT recommend doing jsp scriplets to connect. That logic should be separate. But if you *MUST* do it, here is another example: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97336_01/buslog.102/a83726/basics7.htm

Comment: Ok As you said , I will use a java class to connect to database and compare.  But the problem is , when we enter the same value second time , Instead of going to db table and overwriting existing value , it should display an alert pop up message .  Like in jsp we have  alert(" blah blah .. ");  .                                                                                                      Now if i use java , I have to direct to a different page . Cant we just pop up an alert message , instead of using sendRedirect()  ?

Comment: An JS like alert message is hardly possible, since you've got to query the database. The only way to approach that result would be using Ajax. But if I were you, I would write a query in the Java class which would select the value for the quantity based on the two PKs. According to the number of results that query returns, I would display either a green success panel or a red failure panel on the webpage.

Comment: If you can share your code(jsp), it is easy to understand and provide an answer to your exact matter.How ever it can be added to the code you insert values to database, where ever you do it(may be not the proper way)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution for this.

In the java class , Before I used to have like this : response.sendRedirect("success.jsp");

Now I have changed it as follows :
If the db table already contains the value, no need to update.                               So, response.sendRedirect("success.jsp?msg=operation already completed")           Else, Need to update the db table and display message "Operation completed successfully"
So, response.sendRedirect("success.jsp?msg=operation completed successfully");

I have added a parameter "msg" in success.jsp , and displayed it dynamically according to the requirement.